# Query For getting the Salary of employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
 Insert into Employee values (1,'Abdul Rehman','Street No 12','Kamra Kalan')
 Insert into Employee values (2,'Iram Bhatti','Street No 10','Attock')
 Insert into Employee values (3,'Danial Aziz','Street No 12','Kamra Kalan')
 Insert into Employee values (4,'Kashif Butt','Street No 10','Attock')
 Insert into Employee values (5,'Zohaib Butt','Street No 13','Peshawar')


 insert into Company values (1,'First Bank Co-Operation','Hydrabaad');
 insert into Company values (2,'Small Bank Co-Operation','Kashmir');



 Insert  into Works  values (1,2,5000)
 Insert  into Works  values (2,1,40000)
 Insert  into Works  values (1,3,56000)
 Insert  into Works  values (1,4,8000)
 Insert  into Works  values (2,2,78000)
```

Question:
Write a query for getting the name of employees who earn more than every employee of Small Bank Co operation.

My query Solution:

```
 Select Employee.person_name from Works
 inner join Employee on Employee.person_Id
 =Works.Person_Id inner join Company on
 Company.Company_Id=Works.Company_Id
and  Salary>(Select Salary from works 
 Where Company.Company_name='Small Bank Co-Operation')
```

But This query not works for me how can I get this one?

Comment: ```Create Table Employee (
person_Id int primary key ,
person_name varchar (100),
street varchar(100),
City varchar(100)
)

Create table Works(
Company_Id int,
Person_Id int,
Salary int
)

Create Table Company(
Company_Id int  Primary key ,
Company_name varchar(100),
Company_City varchar(100)
)
```

Comment: Your subquery is wrong. Focus on that first: write out a complete query, with any joins necessary, that returns the max salary of anyone at Small Bank. As a hint, you should start this with `select max(Salary)`. Once you've got that working, returning a single number only, you can then put it back into your original query.

Comment: But They ask me to select the name of employees not the salary

Comment: Yes, but before you can find the names of the employees that earn more than the max salary from Small Bank, you need to find the max salary from Small Bank. So work that out, and then use the query you wrote to find that in your main query.

Comment: @ALI, consider the data tables separately, fisrt think about a way to get all necessary info, then focus on getting the highest salary

Comment: Your subquery returns more than one row, so you cannot compare the salary with `>` as you would do with a single value. You want the salary to be greater than **all** salaries at Small Bank's, so you could use `where salary > ALL (...)` instead, if your DBMS supports this. Anyway, your works table in the suquery is not  linked to the company, so you'd still get incorrect results.

Comment: What *is* your DBMS? You should tag all your SQL questions with the DBMS you are using in order to get appropriate answers.

Comment: Sql Server 2018

Comment: Okay, I've tagged your request with this DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is just to join all of the tables and then find the employee who has a salary equal to the max salary from the works table.

```
SELECT e.person_name
FROM employee e inner join works w
on e.person_Id = w.Person_Id
inner join company c
on w.Company_Id = c.Company_Id
WHERE c.Company_name = 'Small Bank Co-Operation'
and w.Salary = (SELECT max(works.Salary)
                FROM works)
```

Comment: Thats not I needed

Comment: I don't think you worded your question correctly then. This does in fact return the name of the employee with the highest salary for "Small Bank Co-Operation." If several employees make the same amount as the highest salary it will return all of their names.

Answer (score 0):

How much does an employee earn?

```
select person_id, sum(salary)
from works
group by person_id;
```

We can even extend this to see whether this is Small Bank employee:

```
select
  person_id,
  sum(salary),
  max(case when Company_Id = 
                (select Company_Id from company where company_name = 'Small Bank Co-Operation')
      then 1 else 0 end
  ) as is_small_banker
from works
group by person_id;
```

Now, use this to compare:

```
with salaries as
(
  select
    person_id,
    sum(salary) as total,
    max(case when Company_Id = 
                  (select Company_Id from company where company_name = 'Small Bank Co-Operation')
        then 1 else 0 end
    ) as is_small_banker
  from works
  group by person_id
)
select e.person_name
from employee e 
join salaries s on s.person_id = e.person_id
where total > all
(
  select total
  from salaries
  where is_small_banker = 1
)
order by e.person_name;
```

This is just one way to do this. You can do the same with `NOT EXISTS` for example (i.e. where not exists a Small Bank worker with the same or a higher salary).

---

### Update

You have meanwhile tagged your request with SQL Server and told me that you are getting this error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 126 Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Obviously, SQL Server has problems with the conditional aggregation. You can circumvent this by joining the compabny table instead:

```
with salaries as
(
  select
    w.person_id,
    sum(w.salary) as total,
    max(case when c.company_name = 'Small Bank Co-Operation' then 1 else 0 end
       ) as is_small_banker
  from works w
  join company c on c.company_Id = w.company_Id
  group by w.person_id
);
```

### Update 2

If the `works` table could only have one work (company and salary) per employee, the whole query would reduce to:

```
select e.person_name
from employee e 
join works w on w.person_id = e.person_id
where salary > all
(
  select salary
  from works
  where id_company =
    (select company_Id from company where company_name = 'Small Bank Co-Operation')
)
order by e.person_name;
```

Comment: ```Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.```

Comment: Okay, you are using some DBMS (which you are strangely enough still keeping a secret) that doesn't support a subquery inside an aggregation. Then join the company table to the works table instead, so you can access the company name directly.

Comment: No I want to get the employee name from employee table thats why i am also using the Employee table too.

Comment: All I want to do is that get the name of those employees whose salary is more then salary of every Small Bank Co-Operation company Employee

Comment: Look at my query: `select e.person_name from employee e`. I am selecting the emplyee name, too. The works table is in the with clause where the error is reported.

Comment: An employee can have multiple salaries in your data model. So in order to know how much an employee *earns*, we must add up their salaries. This is what I am describing in my answer and this is what "Question: Write a query for getting the name of employees who earn more than every employee of Small Bank Co operation." is asking.

Comment: Lets keeps it simple

Comment: Yep, that removes the main problem. If a person worked only in one company, then the works table would be the salary table (and it would be more appropriate to have company_id and salary directly in the employees table then). Well, if you want to test this: remove the whole with clause and change `salaries` to `works` and `total`to `salary`.

Comment: But now can you make the query without changing the shape of the tables, as I remove the row which creates a problem

Comment: Just read my last comment. Leave the tables as they are and change my query as described. (I'm just saying that if you want to make it a rule that an employee works only in one company, then you'd better change that data model.)

Comment: But we are not allowed to change the structure of tables, I will be very thankful if you make a query with existing table that are shown without changing the structure of database.

Comment: I did that. I decribed how to change my query. Again: remove the whole `with` clause and change `salaries` to `works` and `total` to `salary`.

Comment: I did not able to get your intuition, can you modify and write it in comment

Comment: I forgot that you'd have to lookup the company, too. I've made two updates to my answer.